# Attributes not displaying in all categories

Tags: attributes

I have a site which has been dormant for about a year and half. In between I kept coming back to it to make changes and now I've even forgotten what I had done to it.
Now, I had enabled attributes somehow by watching a youtube tutorial, and now the problem is that those attributes are not showing up in all categories. It's like they are showing up in 2-3, but the rest of the categories are attribute-less. Can anyone help me on this?
For categories with sub-categories, it's working only in the parent category.

Comment: They are not visible in admin or in front-end ?

Comment: not visible in frontend

Comment: Check if they actually have value in admin, or any condition in frontend to display based upon category.

Comment: I've checked all portions of attributes and categories, but there isn't any particular setting that is working. The attributes are simply not working in some categories and no visible problem behind it.

Comment: You'd need to show the code you are using for this. Include that in your question.

Comment: Got the problem. Just had to select "yes" for anchor for each category individually. Solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem on my site today.  I had 2 out of 9 categories that did not display attributes.  I have some product in multiple categories, attributes displayed in one category but not the other so I knew attributes were setup correctly.  In Admin, go to Catalog > Manage Categories and select the category that is not displaying attributes.  Select the tab 'Display Settings' and set attribute 'Is Anchor' to 'Yes'.  This fixed my problem for both categories.